# Solve the equation $3^{2x^2}-2\times3^{x^2+x+6}+3^{2x+12}=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Solve the equation $$3^{2x^2}-2\times3^{x^2+x+6}+3^{2x+12}=0$$

The only thing I was able to do: $$3^{2x^2}-2\times3^{x^2}\times3^x\times3^6+3^{2x}\times3^{12}=0$$ Can you give me a hint?

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=3%5E%282x%5E2%29-2.3%5E%28x%5E2%2Bx%2B6%29%2B3%5E%282x%2B12%29%3D0

Comment: Are the periods supposed to be multiplication?  Please use \cdot to get a centered dot, so 1 \cdot 2 gives $1 \cdot 2$

Answer (score 5):

**HINT**

Consider the following identity:
\begin{align*}
(a - b)^{2} = a^{2} - 2ab + b^{2}
\end{align*}
At the present case, the LHS can be expressed in terms of $a = 3^{x^{2}}$ and $b = 3^{x + 6}$.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Thank you, I got it.

Comment: @yinivem462 you are welcome! I am glad to help.